# Why am I unable to find the template and render from javascript in Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, render

I am using the `link_to :remote => true` and it is running a show_call.js.erb.

```
$("#display-call").html(<%= render :template => "contact_calls/new"%>)
```

However, I get this following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial contact_calls/new with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:prawn_xxx, :prawn, :prawn_dsl, :haml, :erb, :rhtml, :builder, :rjs, :rxml], :formats=>[:js, :html]} in view paths
```

There is a view in app/views/contact_calls/new.html.erb --- but I get this error saying it wants a "partial"?  I just want to render the regular view.

Here is what gets called currently in hew.html.haml:

```
 1 - title "Sending call"
  2 = render :partial => 'call', :call => @call
```

for the contact_call controller I define @call

I moved this into theh _call partial:

```
 1 #main
  2   = render :partial => 'contacts/contactpartial'
  3   %p= link_to call.title, call_path(call)
  4   = render :partial => 'form'
  5   %p= link_to "Back to List", contact_calls_path
```

Answer (score 1):

The filename for partials must start with an underscore; you might call your file `app/views/contacts_calls/_new.html.erb`, but more likely you want to distill the common code into another partial, say `_call.html.erb`, and render it in both templates via something like the following:

```
# new.html.erb
<%= render 'call', :call => @call %>
```

and

```
// show_call.js.erb
$("#display-call").html(<%= render 'call', :call => @call %>);
```

Note that I'm making an assumption about wanting to pass a local variable named `call` to your partial.

You can't render top-level views from within another view. If you want to render some part of another view, you'll have to distill the shared view code into a partial and render it from both top-level views.

Comment: Agreed. I'd also add that in general it's a good idea to name partials that return data from remote calls using something other than one of the seven 'restful' names -- like new, create, etc. In this case maybe calling it `app/views/contacts_calls/_call.html.erb`.

Comment: ahhh....so I can't render another view even remotely...that's helpful...in Rails 2...I was able to do it.....won't this make it non-DRY since it's the same view I use when going directly?

Comment: Partials are *more* DRY. You should be distilling the shared bits of code out into partials, that's what they're for.

Comment: I see...but it's the same as the top-level view...so maybe I should make the top-level view that calls _new to call the partial?  Heh, yes, I see...so my js.erb needs to pass the values in the render as well....

Comment: okay, I tried changing the top level view to call the partial _call...but it's not receiving the local variable....?  I posted what used to be in new and my new _call partial...thanks!